# Roblox studio - attempt to index nil with 'MouseClick'

Tags: lua, roblox

Maybe it's a stupid mistake, but I have this simple script here for opening doors in my key model:

```
function onMouseClick()
game.Workspace.Door1.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage
script.Parent.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage
end

script.Parent:FindFirstChild("ClickDetector").MouseClick:Connect(onMouseClick)
```

But it just stops with an error: *Workspace.Key1.Script:8: attempt to index nil with 'MouseClick'*

Please help me, thanks.

Also I have FindFirstChild("ClickDetector") there because "Clickdetector" doesn't appear in the model until later in the game.

Comment: Has the parent a ClickDetector? You say later in the game, but when it's after you load the script it will crash because there is no ClickDetector at that time. If you add that detector later on you also need to add the event at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the code only executes when the click detector actually exists  in that model.

This is because when you're using `:FindFirstChild()` if it runs when the object does not exist it returns `Nil` to mean that it did not find that object.

Here are some links that explain `:FindFirstChild()` :
https://devforum.roblox.com/t/what-does-findfirstchild-do/2084105 , https://arebeexlua.fandom.com/wiki/FindFirstChild()

Alternatively you could use `:WaitForChild()` which waits until it finds the object that you are looking for. It can be used exactly the same as `:FindFirstChild()` However there is an additional parameter called `timeout` which acts as a time to wait in seconds for the object to exist.

Here are some examples:

`workspace:WaitForChild("Part")` - This will wait forever until a `Part` Exists

`workspace:WaitForChild("Part", 20)` - This will only wait for 20 seconds until a part exists, if the part was not found within 20 seconds it returns `Nil` just like `:FindFirstChild()` would.

Here is a good link that explains the difference between the two Methods:
https://devforum.roblox.com/t/waitforchild-findfirstchild-when-to-use/737481/3

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this instead

```
function onMouseClick()
game.Workspace.Door1.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage
script.Parent.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage
end

script.Parent:WaitForChild("ClickDetector").MouseClick:Connect(onMouseClick)
```

The reason why you should use `WaitForChild()` was because you said that the Clickdetector only appear later in the game.

if it gives out an error that saids like 'infinite yeld possible' then, you should better check the script that creates the ClickDetector.

The reason might be that its name isn't really 'ClickDetector' or its parent was not the part.